# CSS LinearGradient stop offset attribute

Tags: css, svg

I want to receive Linear Gradient output.

But I cannot understand stop-offset attribute too accurately, to use it.

My code and live-showing output below:

```html
<div id="progress">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <linearGradient id="progress" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientTransform="rotate(35)">
            <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#e31cf0" />
            <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#4a96ef" />
        </linearGradient>
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" class="mask" />
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" class="speed zero" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was guessing that this is a kind of meter that shows the progress of something. I changed the circle into a path and animate it using the stroke-dash attribute. I changed the linear gradient into a radial gradient because it matches the circle better.

```js
var offset = 283;
var int = setInterval(function(){
  offset -= 5;
  if(offset < 40) clearInterval(int);
  document.querySelector('path').style.strokeDashoffset = offset;
}, 500)
```

```html
<div id="progress">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="300" height="300">
      <radialGradient id="rg1" cx="20%" cy="0%" r="100%" fx="70%" fy="20%">
        <stop offset="30%"  stop-color="#e31cf0"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#4a96ef"/>
      </radialGradient>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="black" />
      <g transform="translate(50 50)">
         <path transform="rotate(180)" d="M 45,0 A 45,45 0 0 1 0,45 45,45 0 0 1 -45,0 45,45 0 0 1 0,-45 45,45 0 0 1 45,0 Z" stroke="url(#rg1)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="283" stroke-dashoffset="280"/>
      </g>
   </svg>
</div>
```